# Print list of ALL environment variables

Tags: lua

I would like to print a list of all [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and their values. I searched the Stackoverflow and the following questions come close but don't answer me:

- [How to discover what is available in lua environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806593/how-to-discover-what-is-available-in-lua-environment) (it's about Lua environment not the system environment variables)
- [Print all local variables accessible to the current scope in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834579/print-all-local-variables-accessible-to-the-current-scope-in-lua) (again about _G not the os environment variables)
- http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv (this is a good function but I have to know the name of the environment variable in order to call it)

Unlike C, Lua doesn't have `envp**` parameter that's passed to `main()` so I couldn't find a way to get a list of all environment variables. Does anybody know how I can get the **list of the name and value of all *environment variables***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code was extracted from an old POSIX binding.

```
static int Pgetenv(lua_State *L)        /** getenv([name]) */
{
    if (lua_isnone(L, 1))
    {
        extern char **environ;
        char **e;
        if (*environ==NULL) lua_pushnil(L); else lua_newtable(L);
        for (e=environ; *e!=NULL; e++)
        {
            char *s=*e;
            char *eq=strchr(s, '=');
            if (eq==NULL)       /* will this ever happen? */
            {
                lua_pushstring(L,s);
                lua_pushboolean(L,0);
            }
            else
            {
                lua_pushlstring(L,s,eq-s);
                lua_pushstring(L,eq+1);
            }
            lua_settable(L,-3);
        }
    }
    else
        lua_pushstring(L, getenv(luaL_checkstring(L, 1)));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: well, this is one way to solve the problem using C. Apparently there's no pure-Lua function that does this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexStack, as mentioned by Nicol, there is no pure-Lua function because `environ` is not ANSI C, just POSIX.

Answer (score 5):

Standard Lua functions are based on C-standard functions, and there is no C-standard function to get all the environment variables. Therefore, there is no Lua standard function to do it either.

You will have to use a module like [luaex](https://github.com/LuaDist/luaex), which provides this functionality.

Comment: @AlexStack: Not quite. `argv` refers to the command-line arguments passed to the program. `envp` refers to environment variables, but it's non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the lua-posix module. Alternatively, RedHat installations have POSIX routines built-in, but to enable them, you have to do a trick:

```
  cd /usr/lib64/lua/5.1/
  # (replace 5.1 with your version)
  ln -s ../../librpmio.so.1 posix.so
  # (replace the "1" as needed)
  lua -lposix
  > for i, s in pairs(posix.getenv()) do print(i,s,"\n") end
```

The trick is in creating a soft-link to the RPM's "io" directory and to naming the soft-link the same name of the library LUA will attempt to open. If you don't do this, you get:

```
./librpmio.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_librpmio
```

or similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
local osEnv = {}

for line in io.popen("set"):lines() do 
  envName = line:match("^[^=]+")
  osEnv[envName] = os.getenv(envName)
end
```

this would not work in some cases, like "no valid shell for the user running your app"

Comment: It could also fail if some environment variable names or values contain newlines or other funny characters.

Answer (score 1):

An easy 2 liner:

```
    buf = io.popen("env", '*r')
    output = buf:read('*a')
    print(output) -- or do whatever
```